# text index required for $text query in the MongoDB with Express

Tags: mongodb, express, axios

I built a Express back-end which is connected to local MongoDB

when I create a post to find out the specific term, it returns the error like this

```
MongoError: text index required for $text query
```

How can I fix this error?

this is my Express code

```
app.post("/api/search",(req,res)=> {

    const term = req.body.searchTerm;

    console.log(term); // Here I can check the request coming well

    MongoClient.connect(url,(err,db)=> {
        if(err) throw err;

        const dbo = db.db("Exercise");
        dbo.collection("exercise")
            .find({$text:{$search:term}})
            .toArray((error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  return;
                } else {
                    console.log("Success");
                  res.send(result);
                }
              });
    });
});

Thank you in advance!
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do to solve your problem is simple. You can create a "text" on the field that you want search in you collection like this:

```
db.reviews.createIndex( { comments: "text" } )
```

Note: [assumes "comments" is the field as seen in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

However, for the best results you might want to create a [dynamic default Search index in MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/tutorial). It's free and easy. Because it is a dynamic default, you do not need to do any configuration. The results and performance will likely be better if you are powering a search experience.

I hope this info helps.